# How to return same data frame in 'for loop' after passing some function on it, without appending etc.?

Tags: python, list, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

I have three dataframes that I would like to crop, I have defined a function;

```
def croping(data, start_date='2017-04-10 00:00:00', end_date='2018-05-31 21:55:00' ):
    return data.loc[start_date:end_date]
```

I know this is a bit extra but I am trying to learn how to use user-defined functions.

I then want to use this function on the list of dataframes;

```
df_list = [df1, df2, df3]
```

where

```
df1= 
Timestamp                A          B          C          D          E                        
2017-04-01 00:00:00  106.46451   98.94002  118.59085  100.83779  108.89098
2017-04-01 00:05:00  105.74346   98.93000  113.47805   86.77218  105.37943
2017-04-01 00:10:00  105.99000   99.15727  115.48461   96.76406  106.55555
2017-04-01 00:15:00  105.04311   98.93000  112.15814   88.38959 104.71931
...                  ...         ...       ...         ...
```

etc.

I am then trying to run a for loop to crop each dataframe

```
for name in df_list:
    holding = croping(name)
```

if I do it this way I need to then append the holding dataframes together, is there a way that I can call the cropped dataframe a different thing in each iteration? Something like this;

```
for name in df_list:
    name_cropped = croping(name)
```

where name changes in each iteration, so I am left with df1_cropped, df2_cropped etc.

Maybe the best way to do this is not with a for loop, I am still very much learning

Comment: Think about using a dictionary instead of the list.

Answer (score 3):

You have a couple of options. You can index your dataframes by location in a list. In this case, you can use a list comprehension. Using [`pd.DataFrame.pipe`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pipe.html) would be the Pandorable method as it facilitates method chaining:

```
df_list = [df1, df2, df3]
df_croped = [df.pipe(croping) for df in df_list]
```

However, you may find it cleaner to use dictionaries instead:

```
df_dict = dict(enumerate((df1, df2, df3), 1))
df_croped = {k: v.pipe(croping) for k, v in df_dict.items()}
```

You can then access the first dataframe original or uncropped, via `df_dict[0]` or `df_croped[0]` respectively.

Comment: I am still not very confident with dictionaries, which is something I think I need to sort out

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use 2 lists in place of one i.e

```
df_list = [df1, df2, df3]
df_list_updated = []

for name in df_list:
    df_list_updated.append(croping(name))
```